# Wordpress 4.8 - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: wp

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-4.8

After updating to Wordpress 4.8 widgets stop working, I mean the textarea inside has disappeared and I read the following error in console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: wp
Global Code — widgets.php:202
```

Looking into the file I see the line causing the issue:

```
wp.mediaWidgets.init();
```

and so on. There are other blocks related to the `wp` variable but I really cannot understand why it's happening considering that I've already tried to disable all plugins without success. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try switching to one of the default WordPress themes (ex: TwentySeventeen)? If that works, then you know the problem is something with your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rideron89, I'll try again but I already done it. Going mad... :D

Answer (score 0):

How did you update to 4.8? You might try manually updating WordPress. Your issue could be from inconsistent versions of some files. [Source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updated-to-4-8-now-getting-two-fatal-error-messages/)

Check out [these instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update).

If this doesn't work, can you say which `widgets.php` file is causing the problem? I noticed there were a few files with that name in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved manually restoring the Wordpress core and cleaning the **wp-config.php**. Furthermore there was a function in my theme **deferring javascript** and that was the main cause, most likely.